# How to hold a value for a period of time

Tags: lua

New to Lua scripting, so hopefully I'm using the right terminology to describe this, please forgive if I'm not, I'll get better over time....

I'm writing code for a game using Lua. And I have a function that sets a value. Now I need to "hold" this value for a set period of time after which it gets set to another value.

I'm trying to replicate this behavior:
Imagine a car-start key. 
0 = off 
1 = ignition on
2 = ignition on + starter  -- this fires to get the engine to ignite. In real-life, this "start" position 2 is HELD while the starter does its thing, then once the engine ignites, you'd let go and it springs back to = 1 to keep the ignition on while the engine keeps running.

Now imagine instead, a start button and it can not NOT be pushed in **and held in position=2 (like the key)** for the time required for the starter to ignite the engine. Instead, once touched, that should cause the starter to **runs for a set period of time in position 2** and when it senses a certain =>RPM, the starter stops and goes back to position 1, and leaves the engine running.

Similarly, I have a button that when "touched" fires the starter, but that starter event as expected goes from 0 to 2 and back to 1 in a blink. If I set it to be 2 then it fires forever.

I need to hold its phase 2 position in place for 15 seconds, then it can get back to 1

What I have:
A button that has an animated state. (0 off, 1, 2). 
If 0 then 1, if 1 then 2 using phase==2 as the spring step from 2 back to 1
At position == 2, StarterKey = 2
No syntax issues. 
The StarterKey variable is triggered to be =2 at position 2  -- BUT not long enough for the engine to ignite. I need StarterKey=2 to stay as a 2 for 15 seconds. Or, do I need to time the entire if phase==2 stage to be held for longer? Not sure.

What should I be looking at please? Here's a relevant snip..

```
function EngineStart()
  if phase == 0 then
   if ButtonState == 0 then  
       ButtonState = 1    
       StarterKey = 2      -- I tried adding *duration = 15* this event but that does not work
   end
   end
   end
```

- I also have the subsequent *elseif phase == 2* part for when the button is in position == 2 so it springs back to 1 -- that all works fine.

How do I, or what do I need to use, to introduce time for my events and functions? I don't want to measure time, but set event time.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you making a new game or modifying an existing one? If the former, what engine? If the latter, what game?

Comment: Never mind -- I figured out the timer issue by watching a video online. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by watching a Lua tutorial video online (taught me how) + discovered that the sim has a timer function that I then used to set the number of seconds ("time") that the starter key-press stayed in its 2 position, which then fired it long enough for the igniters to do their work. (what to use) 
QED :)) HA!